# VBA code in Excel, Argument not optional, CountIf Error

Tags: vba, excel, countif

I created a code to find instances of the number 1 in column A in Sheet27 but it keeps giving the error 'argument not optional' and highlighting the CountIf part of the code. I want this information to be displayed as a msgbox.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim instances As Long
    instances = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet27")(Columns("A:A"), "1"))

    MsgBox "We Found " & instances & " instances of ", vbInformation, "Alert"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
instances = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet27").Columns("A:A"), "1")
```

Comment: Also wanted to ask if i want it to count more than one criteria, such as "2" and "3" as well, how should i modify the code.

Comment: @SabaAli - `CountIfs` - it's another worksheet function.